error sudo apt update on ubuntu 24.04 noble
i installed ubuntu 24.04 but when i use sudo apt update this error come:
kavus@kavus-HP:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for kavus: 
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu'
Types: deb
URIs: https://ir.ubuntu.sindad.cloud/ubuntu/
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources
Types: deb
URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble-security
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

please help me i don't know what i have to do :(

Try removing the trailing / from the URI entry and see here
